# Calculadora em Java

Tags: java, scanner

Estava tudo indo bem até a parte em que deveria aparecer o resultado.

```
public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1,num2,resul;
         String sinal;
        System.out.println("Olá, entre com o primeiro numero: ");
        num1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Olá, entre com o segundo numero: ");
        num2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Soma (s) Menos (m) Vezes (v) Dividir (d): ");
        resul = in.nextInt();
        sinal = in.nextLine();

        if(sinal.equals ("s"))
        {
            resul = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("Resultado final "+resul);
        }
        else if (sinal.equals ("m"))
        {
            resul = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("Resultado final "+resul);
        }
        else if (sinal.equals ("v"))
        {
            resul = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("Resultado final "+resul);
        }
        else if (sinal.equals("d"))
        {
            resul = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println("Resultado final "+resul);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Não sei não haha, primeira vez em java!

Comment: Luiz, não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Só o fato de vc ter aceito a resposta já indica que ela está resolvida.

Comment: Ops haha, foi mal e obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos problemas é esta linha:

```
resul = in.nextInt();
```

O valor de `resul` será calculado com base nos valores já lidos, então não faz sentido você lê-lo do `Scanner`. Pode remover esta linha.

Em seguida, o `nextLine()` chamado logo depois de um `nextInt()` consome a quebra de linha (o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que o usuário digitou após o número), e o sinal ficará vazio (por isso ele não entra em nenhum dos `if`'s depois).

Em vez disso, você pode usar `next()`:

```
System.out.println("Olá, entre com o primeiro numero: ");
num1 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Olá, entre com o segundo numero: ");
num2 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Soma (s) Menos (m) Vezes (v) Dividir (d): ");
sinal = in.next();
```

---

Outro detalhe é que, ao dividir dois inteiros, o resultado será arredondado (7 / 2 dá 3;  2 / 5 dá zero, etc). Se quiser o resultado mais preciso, com as casas decimais, troque os valores para `double`:

```
double num1, num2, resul;
System.out.println("Olá, entre com o primeiro numero: ");
num1 = in.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Olá, entre com o segundo numero: ");
num2 = in.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Soma (s) Menos (m) Vezes (v) Dividir (d): ");
sinal = in.next();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Vou tentar aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Não tive a oportunidade de testar devido a alguns fatores, e ainda não posso comentar (logo considere isso como um comentário) , porém imagino que o a ordem em que você entra com informações aqui possa ser o problema.
Já que pode estar confundindo o que está armazenado nas variáveis

```
System.out.println("Soma (s) Menos (m) Vezes (v) Dividir (d): ");
sinal = in.nextLine();      
resul = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: Opá, tentei aqui mesmo assim não foi (de qualquer forma obrigado!!)